# Проблема с выводом после нажатия кнопки (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Я раньше выводил всех студентов из БД через этот код, но сейчас добавил бутстрап и как раньше не выводит после клика, в чем может быть ошибка

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<br>
<br>
    <form action="allStudents" method="post">

        <input type="submit" value="Показать всех студентов" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Мой бутстрап

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<br>
<br>
    <form action="allStudents" method="post">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Вывести всех студентов</button>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Самый первый код он выводил в таблице всех студентов из БД, во второй я изменил и добавил бутстрап и он через него не выводит

Comment: Я просто остальные классы не выложил

Comment: я исправил код вот первый пример где он показывал всех студентов, во втором не показывает с бутсрапом

Comment: Сейчас добавлю через минуту

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ просто в коде надо было изменить вот так

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Показать всех студентов">
```